# How to get Min Value from group_concat?

Tags: mysql

This is my query

```
select
  `products`.`id`,
  `products`.`image`,
  `products`.`name`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(product_prices.price) as min_price
from
  `products`
  inner join `product_prices` on `product_prices`.`products_id` = `products`.`id`
group by
  `products`.`id`
limit
  9 offset 0
```

My output is

```
id | image | name | min_price
1    up/...  Pr1     32,43,56,23
```

I want the min_price to be 23 only.
How do i do it.
I tried to use

```
select substring_index(group_concat(product_prices.price order by product_prices.id asc SEPARATOR ','), ',', 1)
```

but its showing the price of the lowest id.
Please Help

This is my fiddle
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4232eb1ddce5a96babdf3119b5aac604

Comment: The data type of the column `price` is `varchar`. Why? It should be a numeric data type.

Comment: If you change its data type to `int` you get the correct result: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3bb7f52a0fbabc017a2fb0c82c6dc03e

Comment: yeah its working and i am stupid

Comment: `MIN(CAST(product_prices.price AS UNSIGNED)) as min_price` this fix is all you need to work -- making your column an UNSIGNED INTEGER rather than a VARCHAR.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your price is not a Number

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `products` (
>  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
>  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE `product_prices` (
>  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>  `price` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
>  `products_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
>  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>  KEY `product_prices_products_id_index` (`products_id`)
> );
>
> insert into products(name) values('PR1');
>
> insert into product_prices (price,products_id) values('34','1');
>
> insert into product_prices (price,products_id) values('324','1');
>
> insert into product_prices (price,products_id) values('456','1');
> ```

> ```
> select
>   `products`.`id`,
>   `products`.`name`,
>  MIN(CAST(product_prices.price AS UNSIGNED)) as min_price
> from
>   `products`
>   inner join `product_prices` on `product_prices`.`products_id` = `products`.`id`
> group by
>   `products`.`id`,
>   `products`.`name`
> limit
>   9 offset 0;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name | min_price
> -: | :--- | --------:
>  1 | PR1  |        34
> ```

> ```
> select
>   `products`.`id`,
>   `products`.`name`,
>  MIN(product_prices.price + 0) as min_price
> from
>   `products`
>   inner join `product_prices` on `product_prices`.`products_id` = `products`.`id`
> group by
>   `products`.`id`,
>   `products`.`name`
> limit
>   9 offset 0;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name | min_price
> -: | :--- | --------:
>  1 | PR1  |        34
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=53ff19541535270a67d50533f66c8e88)*

Comment: yeah that works perfectly, but i changed the datatype. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

> I want the min_price to be 23 only

MIN rather than GROUP_CONCAT ?

```
select
  `products`.`id`,
  `products`.`image`,
  `products`.`name`,
  MIN(product_prices.price + 0) as min_price
from
  `products`
  inner join `product_prices` on `product_prices`.`products_id` = `products`.`id`
group by
  `products`.`id`,
  `products`.`image`, --image in the SELECT should be in the GROUP BY
  `products`.`name`   --name  in the SELECT should be in the GROUP BY
limit
  9 offset 0
```

OR

```
select
  `products`.`id`,
  MAX(`products`.`image`) as image, --if not in the GROUP BY, must be in an aggregate function here
  MAX(`products`.`name`) as name,   --if not in the GROUP BY, must be in an aggregate function here
  MIN(product_prices.price) as min_price
from
  `products`
  inner join `product_prices` on `product_prices`.`products_id` = `products`.`id`
group by
  `products`.`id`
limit
  9 offset 0
```

But you can't (shouldn't, even though MySQL lets you) mention columns in the SELECT that are neither in the GROUP BY or in an aggregate function (like MIN)

If ONLY_FULL_GROUPBY mode is off (in mySQL) then you get away with how you wrote your query (you only grouped by ID, you neither grouped nor aggregated the name/image) because it effectively just picks a random single value from the resultset per ID. It's not ideal though because a) other databases don't let you get away with it and b) it doesn't guarantee you get a consistent resultset out over time. which can lead to obscure and difficult to trace bugs

Comment: Its still showing the wrong value

Comment: Thats why i turned to group_concat, maybe i can find the min value returned in the group_concat. Product can have different prices because of different sizes. The prices are in product_prices

Comment: `But you can't (shouldn't, even though MySQL lets you) mention columns in the SELECT that are neither in the GROUP BY or in an aggregate function (like MIN)` this is not entirely true in general and probably wrong in this particular case. Sql standard allows you to list columns in the select list that are functionally dependent on a grouped column without bring part of the group by clause or being aggregated. The id column is presumably the primary key, so any other column from the same table would be functionally dependent on its value.

Comment: *"Its still showing the wrong value"* - really? What value is it showing?

Comment: Therefore the query in the question is likely to work even with full group by sql mode turned on. Most leading database products support this syntax.

Comment: fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4232eb1ddce5a96babdf3119b5aac604

Comment: min_price should be 32 as shown in the fiddle

Comment: @Shadow It depends which version of MySQL is used. MySQL 8.0 can recognize functional dependencies, so if you group by `id` like in this query, then other columns of the same table can be in the select-list. But earlier versions of MySQL return an error for _any_ column in the select-list and not in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @shadow I know the point you're making, but honestly you're digging to a deeper level than most people will ever go (and I think you know the point I'm making too). "Fully specify your group/aggregations" is easy to remember and explain. "Work out the functional dependencies in your entire query to ensure that you're omitting the correct set of columns" is that "phd level" of "step beyond" that most people won't go. Bear in mind that here we're dealing with a question based on the fact that the difference between varchar and int is not understood

Comment: @ShahRukh do you know the difference between integer `32` and string `'32'`, and, for example, why `'320'` is less than `'34'`? I've modified my answer to perform a numeric conversion before the MIN is selcted, now that you've clarified that you've stored all your prices as strings.. but really you should fix the underlying problem; **don't store prices as strings**

Comment: I dont know , i think its just comparing the first number first, then when they are same maybe it goes to second and see that 2 is less than 4 and hence 320 is less than 34. I am just guessing, i'm not sure

Comment: You are indeed correct; your strings are compared thus (and hence MySQL really wasn't making a mistake when it said that '320' was less than '34') - and it is just one of a list of very good reasons why things that are specific datatypes (dates, numbers etc) shouldn't be stored as strings

Comment: @CaiusJard then just not make this incorrect point in your answer. Giving people incorrect advice will lead to confusion later on.

Comment: @shadow Learning is a constant peeling of the onion of abstraction. You wouldn't have much luck nipping into your local elementary school and telling them "don't teach 4 year olds that if they have 2 sweets they can't give away 3 - of course you can; it's negative numbers, silly! Oh and don't tell your 9 year olds you can't square root a negative.. In fact might as well just jump straight to teaching the 4 year olds imaginary numbers, N dimensions and quantum physics". No. "Group or aggregate your columns" is fine and means they wont be confused when the next project is  SQL server. But..

Comment: @shadow do feel free to leave your valid comments to persist (or better still, write an answer that goes into great and fine grained detail about how I oversimplified this answer too much), so that others can benefit from a sermon in functional dependence or have their interest piqued and go read deeper about it themselves. For now I've chosen what I feel is an appropriate level of teaching to confer with this in this post, the primary mission of course being "this is a varchar and that is integer". I'm not disagreeing with you in any way, I'm just saying "your suggestion is too deep"